# About Scopus journals

Tags: journals, paper-submission, online-publication, scopus

I would like  to submit an article in IJEAT Indian  journal for my  thesis but  has  what is called APC fee 
Is this journal a scopus journal?
Is it a ligible publication for my thesis If i pay  the APC?
Does all journals includ APC fee ?

Answer (score 2):

I would answer all your questions one by one.

> Question 1:Is this journal a scopus journal?
>   Answer: In order to know if it is indexed by Scopus you need to visit the website of the journal and check it. Usually journals provide that information in their homepage.
>
> Question 2: Is it a good journal for your thesis?
>   Answer: It is impossible for an arbitrary person in this website to comment about the impact of the journal you have chosen for publication.
>   Your co-authors(if any), advisor, peers are more likely to help you in this regard.
>   You can check if this journal is indexed in leading databases like Web of Science, Science Citation Index to get a rough overview about the impact of the journal.
>
> Question 3: Do all journals include APC?
>   Answer: Not necessarily. Most good journals are published by leading publishers like Elsevier, Taylor Francis, Springer and many more and hence don't charge an APC.
>   But charging an APC does not imply that the journal is a bad journal.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I would add article processing charges (APCs) are predominantly for open-access journals (since they don't make money off subscriptions).  IJEAT is open access, so the APC is expected.

Comment: I assume you mean "not all open access journals change an APC." Which is why I said "predominantly".